# Entity Framework DbContext works in one project but not in another in the same solution

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

So this is a bit of a weird one.

I'm currently prototyping a project and part of it currently involves two console applications in the same VS solution. The `DbContext` class is in it's own class library and both console applications have identical references and using statements. Console application #1 works exactly as expected. Queries to the `DbContext` in console application #2 just return Null. Copying a code block that works in application 1 just returns null in application 2.

Anyone have a clue what's going on here?

No errors are thrown during debug.

Comment: Did you replicate the connection strings between the projects?

Comment: OK so I'm an idiot and this was it.  I wrote the original project so long ago I forgot I added the connection string to the configuration not just to the DbContext class library.